# database connection in java with separated class

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I wrote a Java code to connect to the mysql database in the main method, and I success and get results.
But when I separate the database code in separated class I have a problem with connection to database however I do nothing

this the code:

```
package database;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DataBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        //Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javadb", "root", "123");
        System.out.println("sadsa");
        ConnectToDatabase db = new ConnectToDatabase("javadb", "root", "123");
        System.out.println("sadsa");

        String sqlStatement =    "SELECT  *\n" +
                                    "FROM `javadb`.`user`\n" +
                                    " LIMIT 1000;";


        ResultSet result = db.makeQuery(sqlStatement);

        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result.getString("ID")
                    + " " + result.getString("UserName")
                    + " " + result.getString("Password")
                    );
        }

        db.closeConnection();

    }

}
```

The separated Class:

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ConnectToDatabase {

    // Database Variables
    private final String databaseName;// = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/javadb";  //URL
    private final String databaseUserName;// = "root";
    private final String databasePassword;// = "123";
    private Connection connect;
    private Statement sqlStatement;

    // Connect to Database
    public ConnectToDatabase( String givenDatabaseName,String givenDatabaseUserName, String givenDatabasePassword) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.databaseName = givenDatabaseName;
        this.databaseUserName = givenDatabaseUserName;
        this.databasePassword = givenDatabasePassword;

        this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+givenDatabaseName, givenDatabaseName, givenDatabasePassword);
        this.sqlStatement = this.connect.createStatement();
    }

    public ResultSet makeQuery(String givenStatement) throws SQLException{
        setSqlStatement(givenStatement);
        return sqlStatement.executeQuery(givenStatement);
    }



    public String getDatabaseUserName() {
        return databaseUserName;
    }
    public String getDatabasePassword() {
        return databasePassword;
    }
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }    
    public void setSqlStatement(Statement sqlStatement) {
        this.sqlStatement = sqlStatement;
    }
    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
        connect.close();
    }

    private void setSqlStatement(String givenStatement) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Note:
In main method if I write the same information to connect directly that will work right:

```
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javadb", "root", "123");
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'javadb'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at database.ConnectToDatabase.<init>(ConnectToDatabase.java:27)
    at database.DataBase.main(DataBase.java:15)
Java Result: 1
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not passing the right parameter values when you create `ConnectToDatabase` instance. Can you show that part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the port no.
like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadb
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have specified port number earlier but in separated class port number is missing.

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadb

Comment: Are you sure the port number is 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Pablo Santa Cruz:
that it:

the calling:

```
ConnectToDatabase db = new ConnectToDatabase("javadb", "root", "123");
```

the method:

```
public ConnectToDatabase( String givenDatabaseName,String givenDatabaseUserName, String givenDatabasePassword) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.databaseName = givenDatabaseName;
        this.databaseUserName = givenDatabaseUserName;
        this.databasePassword = givenDatabasePassword;

        this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+givenDatabaseName, givenDatabaseName, givenDatabasePassword);
//        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"
//        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
        this.sqlStatement = this.connect.createStatement();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is error in providing  username and password for the DriverManager class in ConnectTo Database class

this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+givenDatabaseName, givenDatabaseName, givenDatabasePassword);

Here you are giving Database(givenDatabaseName) name two times instead of Database user(givenDatabaseUserName) name;

Hope it helps

Comment: did it works then give mark this as answered question ..it helps others